# How to check duplicate rows while inserting in datagridview in c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to check entire row in `DatagridView` is duplicate or not while inserting row. If a row is duplicate then give error msg, otherwise add entire row to `DatagridView`. Let me know solution or any alternative. 
Thanks.

```
//This is my sample code:I know this code is wrong
List<string> listUserID = new List<string>();
List<string> listPlantID = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < dgvTableInfo.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
   string UserID = dgvTableInfo.Rows[i].Cells["UserID"].Value.ToString();
   string PlantName = dgvTableInfo.Rows[i].Cells["PlantID"].Value.ToString();
   if ((!listUserID.Contains(UserID, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) || (!listPlantID.Contains(PlantName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
   {
      listUserID.Add(dgvTableInfo.Rows[i].Cells["UserID"].Value.ToString());
      listPlantID.Add(dgvTableInfo.Rows[i].Cells["PlantID"].Value.ToString());
   }
   else
   {
      GESDialogBox.Show(this, @"User with same userid and plantid is already exist, please choose unique userid and plantid ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
      return;
    }
}
```

[datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ8f0.jpg)

Comment: I'm not very sure what you're doing but I would recommend you to use a   `HashSet<string>` for both `UserId`s and `PlantId`s, it's faster looking into a hash set than into a list.

Comment: Rather than your `for` loop, which you may or may not know misses the last row, prefer `foreach` which is easier to read, and as a side benefit will save you the expense of multiple indexed lookups. Also, since you went to the trouble of putting values in `UserID` and `PlantID`, use those variables when you add to the lists. Then you need to tell us in what way your code is not doing what you want.

Comment: @dcg ok thanks.I want to just check any rows in datagridview is duplicate or not while inserting new row in datagridview

Comment: Is dgvTableInfo a datagridview? Where are you actually adding records to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways, a simple way is to keep a separate collection of keys, and check that. See below for example.

```
        var keys = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dgvTableInfo.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            var userID = dgvTableInfo.Rows[i].Cells["UserID"].Value.ToString();
            var plantName = dgvTableInfo.Rows[i].Cells["PlantID"].Value.ToString();
            var key = userID + plantName;

            if (!keys.Contains(key))
            {
                keys.Add(key);
            }                
            else
            {
                GESDialogBox.Show(this, @"User with same userid and plantid is already exist, please choose unique userid and plantid ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks !It works for me  but I wanted to compare with entire row

Comment: Make changes to add all items to the key, or a better method would to be to create a hash of the record you are trying to insert.